# Can TeeChart draw value label at cursor point?

Tags: html, teechart

I'm looking for HTML5 chart that can show value at cursor point like this

http://www.tradeviewforex.com/forex-blog/tip-14-how-to-use-the-crosshair-on-metatrader-4

I found StockChartX can do this 
http://developer.modulusfe.com/stockchartx_html5/

(click Draw -> Annotation)

but I can effort this price :P

Thanks for answer!

Ps. Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

Something similar can be done with the Annotation tool in TeeChart HTML5. See the example [here](http://www.steema.com/files/public/teechart/html5/v2012.12.14.1.4/demos/extra/annotations.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can format a tool tip, if that is the need.

```
tip = new Tee.ToolTip(Chart1);
Chart1.tools.add(tip);

tip.format.font.style = "11px Verdana";
tip.render = "canvas";
tip.onshow = function (tool, series, index) {
    scaling = 2;
    poindex = index;
}
tip.onhide = function () {
    scaling = 0;
    poindex = -1;
}
tip.ongettext = function (tool, text) {

    var txt = tool.currentSeries.title + ":\n" + "Value: " + text + tool.currentSeries.units + "\n" + jsonDataArray[0].evDataTime[tool.currentIndex] + " (ms)";
    model.MouseOverY(text + tool.currentSeries.units);
    model.MouseOverX(jsonDataArray[0].evDataTime[tool.currentIndex] + " (ms)");
    model.SelectedSeries(tool.currentSeries.title);
    return txt;
}
```

Comment: oops ignore my 'model.'  just the text part.  the rest is for some other purpose.  I just pasted in code w/o thinking